# Vaadin - JS executing before loading page

Tags: jquery, vaadin

I am trying to add jquery in Vaadin 6.x, but vaadin is executing js before loading page, so jquery tags are not recognized and does not load on page.

I am executing jquery function like following

```
public void attach()
 getApplication().getMainWindow().executeJavaScript("alert('attached');$('a.media').media();");
```

but alert statement and jquery function executes before loading page, so jquery component fails to load.

If I execute this script in `setTimeout()` of javascript with delay of 2-3 seconds then jquery works fine.

Does anyone know how to get event in vaadin which tells exactly at what time vaadin load page?

Answer (score 1):

With jQuery, you can use this:

```
$(function() {
    // Insert your code here
});
```

This use the `.ready()` function. It will be executed when the document has been totaly loaded.

[See the reference](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)